# Get average value without filling all fields and without button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have 3 input boxes which I want to use it to make an average value from those boxes in a readonly input box without clicking any button (just by changing values).

Here is the html:

```html
input1: <input name="1" id="1" value="" ><br>
input2: <input name="2" id="2" value="" ><br>
input3: <input name="3" id="3" value="" ><br><br>
output: <input name="output" id="4" value="" readonly>
```

And here is the script:

```js
var input = $('[name="1"],[name="2"],[name="3"]'),
    input1 = $('[name="1"]'),
    input2 = $('[name="2"]'),
    input3 = $('[name="3"]'),
 input4 = $('[name="output"]');
input.change(function () {
    var val1 = (isNaN(parseInt(input1.val()))) ? 0 : parseInt(input1.val());
    var val2 = (isNaN(parseInt(input2.val()))) ? 0 : parseInt(input2.val());
    var val3 = (isNaN(parseInt(input3.val()))) ? 0 : parseInt(input3.val());
    input4.val((val1 + val2 + val3)/3);
});
```

However, I want to have the average value without filling all 3 input boxes and the divider is based on how many textboxes I input.
Like when I input value in textbox1 and textbox2, the output will be like (textbox1+textbox2)/2 rather than (textbox1+textbox2+0)/3.

I'm quite sure the problem is in "input4.val((val1 + val2 + val3)/3);" line.
But I can't figure out how to write the proper code

Comment: Check my answer as the one you accepted has some issues (see my comment).

Comment: You confuse me, Sir. Are you the same person as mr. Mamun?

Comment: No. I am not. I just posted a separate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *input* event instead of change. You can use `filter()` and `map()` to get the array of non-empty input. Then use `reduce()` to find the sum and finally divide that by the length of the array to get the result.

Try the following:

```js
var input = $('[name="1"],[name="2"],[name="3"]'),
    input1 = $('[name="1"]'),
    input2 = $('[name="2"]'),
    input3 = $('[name="3"]'),
    input4 = $('[name="output"]');
input.on('input', function (el) {
    var vArray = input.filter(function(i,el){
      return !isNaN(this.value.trim()) && $(el).val().trim() != "";
    }).map((j,k) => Number(k.value)).get();
    var res = '';
    if(vArray.length > 0)
      res = vArray.reduce((a,c) => a+c,0)/vArray.length;
    input4.val(res);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
input1: <input name="1" id="1" value=""><br>
input2: <input name="2" id="2" value="" ><br>
input3: <input name="3" id="3" value="" ><br><br>
output: <input name="output" id="4" value="" readonly>:
```

Comment: when only input1 is filled the average should be 4 not 1.333

Comment: 4? Why should it be 4?

Comment: @AshayMandwarya yes. It should be 4 instead of 1.333.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I'm hoping like when we only have 1 input, the divider is only 1. If we have 2 inputs, the divider becomes 2. And so on.

Comment: Good, except that it will fail if you don't enter a number. Also it displays `NaN` when emptying all inputs.

Comment: @MrUpsidown, Yes I noticed that before I marked this answer, Sir. But it only happens if we input the number and we delete it again. Still, there is no problem to me since my form which includes these textboxes requires at least one input. :)

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr.@MrUpsidown for the information. :)

Comment: @MrUpsidown, I think the updated answer fulfills the exception now.....

Comment: @amuntazar, the exception pointed out by MrUpsidown has been solved in the updated answer.......

Comment: Thank you, Sir. But I have already modified it into my real assignment and submitted it to my lecturer. He hasn't said anything so far. Although I will update it for my personal study. :)
Thank you again, Sir.

Comment: @amuntazar, I will suggest you to play with the code (specially `filter()`, `map()`, `get()`, `isNaN()`, `reduce()` etc.), so that you can understand how the code is working

Answer (score 0):

jQuery version

```js
$('input.input').on('blur', function() {

  let values = [];

  $('input.input').each(function() {

    let value = $(this).val();

    if (value && !isNaN(value) && !(/^ *$/.test(value))) {

      values.push(Number($(this).val()));
    }
  });

  if (values.length) {

    $('input.output').val(values.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    }) / values.length);

  } else {

    $('input.output').val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputs">
  input1: <input class="input" name="1" id="1" value=""><br> input2: <input class="input" name="2" id="2" value=""><br> input3: <input class="input" name="3" id="3" value=""><br><br>
</div>

output: <input class="output" name="output" id="4" value="" readonly>
```